# I need to get the corresponding number after * in the string

Tags: php, string

In the development of PHP, I encountered a problem. I need to get the corresponding number after * in the string, which is the number after each * number. If a single number, I can think of using substr, but many have not yet thought of solutions. Please enlighten us.
Like this：

first string * 2 + second string * 4 + third string * 9

Comment: I need take out 2 ,4,9

Comment: Will it always be spaced that way? You could `explode()` into an array and loop through the values, checking for numeric-ness

Comment: yes,It will always be so separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi is the number still part of the string ? if does, maybe you can use explode.

```
<?php
  $num = "* 2 * 3 * 5";
  print_r (explode("*",$str));
?>
```

I hope it helped you. :)

-------UPDATED-----------------

```
$str = 'first string * 2 + second string * 4 + third string * 9';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: um,i think that's not good,because string is 'first string * 2 + second string * 4 + third string * 9',if like you write print,is Array ( [0] => first [1] => 1+second [2] => 7+third  )

Comment: ooowww or how about this one. i will add message to my previous comment. just refer to it.

Comment: wow,amazing.I think I learned something new from you. Thank you.

Comment: does it helped ?

Comment: sure,I forgot it :preg_match_all,I look's like idiot. :)